# How to write specific data to a smart card using Python

Tags: python, digital-signature, smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc

In my project I'm trying to use a smart card for the purpose of creating digital signature for a specific data.

I'm working with the smart card reader ACR38U-I1 and Linux OS (more precisely with the Raspbian OS)

I already installed all the needed drivers for this device and additional libraries such as pcsc, pcsc-lite ...

Also I got private/public gpg keypair for making the digital signature.
As I understand the concept of making digital signature using smart card I have to write the private key to this card and read it when I need to create a signature.

And in this situation I faced with a problem that I don't know how to do this.

I opened pcsc-lite documentation [1] and couldn't find a write methods or examples how to write data to card
https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/api/group__API.html [1]

I'll be grateful if somebody could direct me on the right way.

Comment: *As I understand the concept of making digital signature using smart card I have to write the private key to this card and read it when I need to create a signature.* - that's not how smart cards should be used for signing. Yes, you write the private key onto the card. But it should be a region on the card one can only write to, the key should only be used by an application on the card which generates signatures.

Comment: You mean I must write an application that will be executed right on the smart card ? I thought I can do it in my application that uses this smart card reader. Is it possible ?

Comment: *I thought I can do it in my application that uses this smart card reader. Is it possible ?* - If your smart card offers you such a read/write data bin, you can do so. But in that case the smart card would not offer the security one expects from a smart card. A PKCS12 file on your hard drive would offer the same small degree of security.

Comment: Which card are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Wanted to write a comment, but it got quite long...)

(EDIT: While writing this I did not realize that you are working in a non-x86 environment, so this answer is probably useless unless you have a choice to go for x86 (intel edison maybe?))

This is not a solution, but *might* be a good direction (I have no experience with this particular card):

There is a [PKCS#11 driver](http://www.rutoken.ru/support/download/pkcs/) for the card which *probably* provides some access to its services (pkcs11 is a standardized API to access cryptographic tokens, see [here](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/pkcs-11-cryptographic-token-interface-standard.htm)).

With this *driver* (assuming it works and provides appropriate mechanisms) you have some choices to continue:

- use it directly from `c` code (works for me)
- use a [python wrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pykcs11) (have no experience with this way, but your question implies python is desired)
- use openssl (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/OpenSC/engine_pkcs11/blob/master/README.md) or [here](https://nlnetlabs.nl/downloads/publications/hsm/hsm.pdf) -- this worked for me some time ago)
- use it with [gpg](http://gnupg-pkcs11.sourceforge.net/) (never tried and would not recommend at all)

---

It might be a good idea to verify first that the pkcs11 driver is working (you can do that using firefox browser, see e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/PKCS11/Module_Installation)).

---

Additional notes:

- I recommend to initialize the card and generate the keys with vendor provided utilities and use the pkcs11 driver only to actually sign some data (this way avoids many troublesome parts).
- Do google for pkcs11 and related stuff, this "extended comment" is just an another "point of view"

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm already installed PyKCS11 to my raspbian os (wrapper for PKCS 11 on the Python). And will move into this direction

Comment: @Tequila I have googled [this](http://forum.rutoken.ru/topic/1718/) and [this](https://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/AktivRutokenECP) -- maybe the `opensc-pkcs11.so` will be able to handle your token under arm (so you would not need the pkcs11 driver from the vendor page which is x86 only).

Answer (score 2):

The *typical* approach is:

- **generate** the key (pair) on the smart card; this has the advantage, that no malicious software will be able to grab the private key since it will never leave the card.
- send the command to generate a signature to the card, e.g. with the hash value of the data to sign

*Reading* the key from the smart card discards all the security a smart card provides. The most common way to generate a signature is using a PKCS 11 software, but it may be difficult to find one for Raspbian. I would recommend to find a card directly supported by GPG. That way you will not need to learn in detail about all the necessary topics.

Comment: According to this http://gnupg-pkcs11.sourceforge.net/man.html  gpg protocol is compatible with PKCS 11. In that case my smart card should support pgp too.

Comment: But when I run command gpg --card-status in terminal it detects my card reader but don't see inserted smart card

Comment: @tequila: From these facts I would conclude, that your card is NOT supported by gpg. By the way, for a card fresh from the factory this is to be expected. You need a capable platform and an appropriate personalization. For a start see this [specification](http://www.g10code.com/docs/openpgp-card-3.0.pdf).